# How to implement "press space to pause html5 video" except when input is focused? (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

I'm looking to implement a space-to-pause system for a HTML5 video on my site via jquery, but what I find is that when I've clicked on an input on the same page, adding a space to the text input doesn't work. It just keeps playing/pausing the video.

What I'm looking to do is some kind of if statement that says "if input is not focused, press space to pause video", but also something to repeatedly check this condition so it doesn't happen just once.

I was almost successful using setInterval to do this but jquery's timing is completely imprecise and just leads to the video only pausing sometimes.

Current space-to-pause code is as follows.

```
    $(window).keypress(function(e) {
  var video = document.getElementById("vid");
  if (e.which == 32) {
    if (video.paused)
      video.play();
    else
      video.pause();
  }
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest checking the target of your click event and working based on that! Something like this should work

```js
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
  const video = document.getElementById("vid");

  // check if keypress event originates from an input and if so; NOOP
  const nodeName = e.target.nodeName;
  if (nodeName && nodeName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT") { return; }

  if (e.which == 32) {
    if (video.paused) {
      video.play();
    } else {
      video.pause();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video controls id="vid" style="width: 400px; display:block;">
  <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<input type="text" value="write here!">
```

Comment: Yes this is the right track... I get a bit of an issue with it though. Namely how (only sometimes) it pauses the video when space is clicked, but immediately resumes the video after the space bar is let go. Aside from that it works well (for some reason it doesn't work with my complex video page, but that's down to my code so I've gotta work that out). Good answer.

Comment: Somehow the issue vanished after I added e.preventDefault() to the code... Works excellently. I also had "video" already declared as a variable so had to rename the const. Marked as best answer.

Comment: @RaphaelToast Glad you found a solution! Yeah I think that happens when the video element is focused - by default when you press space and the video element has the focus that pauses/unpauses the player and then the javascript again pauses/unpauses, causing your issue. That's also why e.preventDefault() fixes it as it well, prevents the default functionality of pressing space on a video element :D Good solution!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks again!